# how to set start or end date of antD rangePicker to empty

Tags: reactjs, antd, daterangepicker

within my application I'm using `RangePicker` of `antd`. I've range limit, so if the selected range is longer than a week, I want to set endDate to empty. I tried to set it to empty string and null, none did work out. Dates returned to previous values. Does anyone know how to set date value to empty?

Here is my `onChange` function to catch and implement date change.

```
  const handleValuesChange = (newValues) => {
    const selectedRange = formatDate(newValues);
    if (Math.abs(selectedRange[0].diff(selectedRange[1], 'days')) > dateRangeLimitInDays) {
      setRangeValues([newValues[0], '']);
    }
    else {
      setRangeValues(selectedRange);
      handleChange(selectedRange);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the second value to null works fine for me using [Antd Rangepicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#RangePicker).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

const App = () => {
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

  return (
    <RangePicker
      onCalendarChange={(value) => {
        console.log(value);
        setDates([value[0], null]);
      }}
      value={dates}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Working [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-sammet-h27ut?file=/index.js).

Please add a minimal, reproducable example as CodeSandBox or Stackblitz if you need further investigations.